# Catching errors with Ruby Twitter gem, caching methods using delayed_job: What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, delayed-job, rescue, twitter-gem

**What I'm doing**

I'm using the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) (a Ruby wrapper for the Twitter API) in my app, which is run on [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com). I use [Heroku's Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) to periodically run caching tasks that use the twitter gem to, for example, update the list of retweets for a particular user. I'm also using [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) so scheduler calls a rake task, which calls a method that is 'delayed' (see scheduler.rake below). The method loops through "authentications" (for users who have authenticated twitter through my app) to update each authorized user's retweet cache in the app.

**My question**

**What am I doing *wrong*?** For example, since I'm using Heroku's Scheduler, is delayed_job redundant? Also, you can see I'm not catching (rescuing) any errors. So, if Twitter is unreachable, or if a user's auth token has expired, everything chokes. This is obviously dumb and terrible because if there's an error, the entire thing chokes and ends up creating a failed delayed_job, which causes ripple effects for my app. I can see this is bad, but I'm not sure what the best solution is. How/where should I be catching errors?

I'll put all my code (from the scheduler down to the method being called) for one of my cache methods. **I'm really just hoping for a bulleted list (and maybe some code or pseudo-code) berating me for poor coding practice and telling me where I can improve things.**

I have seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726859/rescuing-from-twitter-gem), which helps me a little with the begin/rescue block, but I could use more guidance on catching errors, and one the higher-level "is this a good way to do this?" plane.

**Code**

Heroku Scheduler job:

```
rake update_retweet_cache
```

scheduler.rake (in my app)

```
task :update_retweet_cache => :environment do
  Tweet.delay.cache_retweets_for_all_auths
end
```

Tweet.rb, update_retweet_cache method:

```
def self.cache_retweets_for_all_auths
  @authentications = Authentication.find_all_by_provider("twitter")

  @authentications.each do |authentication|
    authentication.user.twitter.retweeted_to_me(include_entities: true, count: 200).each do |tweet|
      # Actually build the cache - this is good - removing to keep this short
    end
  end
end
```

User.rb, twitter method:

```
def twitter
  authentication = Authentication.find_by_user_id_and_provider(self.id, "twitter")
  if authentication
    @twitter ||= Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => authentication.oauth_token, :oauth_token_secret => authentication.oauth_secret)
  end
end
```

**Note:** As I was posting this, I noticed that I'm finding all "twitter" authentications in the "cache_retweets_for_all_auths" method, then calling the "User.twitter" method, which specifically limits to "twitter" authentications. This is obviously redundant, and I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First what is the exact error you are getting, and what do you want to happen when there is an error?

Edit:

If you just want to catch the errors and log them then the following should work.

```
def self.cache_retweets_for_all_auths
  @authentications = Authentication.find_all_by_provider("twitter")

  @authentications.each do |authentication|
    being
      authentication.user.twitter.retweeted_to_me(include_entities: true, count: 200).each do |tweet|
        # Actually build the cache - this is good - removing to keep this short
      end
     rescue => e
       #Either create an object where the error is log, or output it to what ever log you wish.
     end
  end
end
```

This way when it fails it will keep moving on to the next user but will still making a note of the error. Most of the time with twitter its just better to do something like this then try to do with each error on its own. I have seen so many weird things out of the twitter API, and random errors, that trying to track down every error almost always turns into a wild goose chase, though it is still good to keep track just in case.

---

Next for when you should use what.

You should use a scheduler when you need something to happen based on time only, delayed jobs for when its based on an user action, but the 'action' you are going to delay would take to long for a normal response. Sometimes you can just put the thing plainly in the controller also.

***So in other words***

The scheduler will be fine as long as the time between updates **X** is less then the time it will take for the update to happen, time **Y**.

If **X < Y** then you might want to look at calling the logic from the controller when each indvidual entry is accessed, isntead of trying to do them all at once. The idea being you would only update it after a certain time as passed so. You could store the last time update either on the model itself in a field like twitter_udpate_time or in a redis or memecache instance at a unquie key for the user/auth.

But if the individual update itself is still too long, then thats when you should do the above, but instead of doing the actually update, call a delayed job.

You could even set it up that it only updates or calls the delayed job after a certain number of views, to further limit stuff.

**Possible Fancy Pants**

Or if you want to get really fancy you could still do it as a cron job, but have a point system based on views that weights which entries should be updated. The idea being certain actions would add points to certain users, and if their points are over a certain amount you update them, and then remove their points. That way you could target the ones you think are the most important, or have the most traffic or show up in the most search results etc etc.

---

Next off a nick picky thing.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

You should be using

```
@authentications.find_each do |authentication|
```

instead of

```
@authentications.each do |authentication|
```

find_each pulls in only 1000 entries at a time so if you end up with a lof of Authentications you don't end up pulling a crazy amount of entries into memory.

Comment: Hi - thanks for your great reply! First, I'm not sure WHICH error I'm afraid of because it's been a while since I got one. So that's why I'm thinking, "Well, why not just make sure I catch ANY error from Twitter so it doesn't bomb things?" Once I start seeing the errors that've been caught, I can get more granular/precise.

Comment: Next, I should say the reason I'm using a job/delayed_job is that the cache updates take quite a while. Sometimes the job will run for many minutes (even for a single user). So I'm building the cache periodically (say, once an hour) and removing old entries once a day. That way, there's no lag when loading the summary page (that uses Twitter data) AND my cache doesn't become enormous. Finally, your "should be, instead of" block shows the same thing twice. But I'm very interested to see your suggestion. Could you please correct that?

Comment: sorry about that, should be .find_each instead of .each. Will update answer in a second.

Comment: This is a great answer - thanks for taking time to respond to all the different aspects of my question, and for providing good examples and explanations. I really appreciate it!

Comment: PS I like your idea of assigning points for views, and updating the cache for those with higher points. That's something I've wondered about: What if they authenticate to Twitter, but then never actually look at the data? That's a lot of dyno time to build a cache that will never be seen. It would be pretty easy to implement that, too. Thanks again!